# jQuery UI Sortable - Using setTimeout to enable sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI Sortable and I don't want to enable sorting until the user clicks and holds down the mouse on the sortable element for about a second or so. Currently i'm trying to use setTimeout.

```
$(function() {

    var globalTimer = 0;

    $("li").on("mousedown", function() {

      globalTimer = setTimeout(function() {

        $(".sortable").sortable({
          stop: function() {

            $(".sortable").sortable("disable");

          }
        }).sortable("enable");
    }, 400);
});

    $("li").on("mouseup mouseleave", function() {

      clearTimeout(globalTimer);

    });
});
```

This is making the items sortable after clicking and holding for 400 ms, then releasing, then clicking again. I would like them to be sortable after clicking and holding for 400 ms right away.

Here is a JSFiddle to better illustrate the problem [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jcc6xkf/2/)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the delay option still allows sorting when dragging the mouse out of the sortable element. I'm looking to stop the sorting on both mouseup and mouseleave.